# Loop over two variables at a time in VB

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to loop over two variables at the same time in VB?

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = k; i < j; i++) {
    DoSomeStuff()
}
```

I edited the message to make it more clear. In my case, `k` is a variable that I can't directly access without a cost so I need to cache it.

I tried `For i As Integer = 0 To 5 And j As Integer = 0 To 5` but it looks like VB won't accept me caching a value this way.

Comment: If the two variables are always going to have the same value, why do you need them both?  Aside from that, what have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: C# can do it with a `for` loop but VB can't. You can do the equivalent with a `Do` or `While` loop.

Comment: I edited the post. I need to cache a variable that I can't directly access. How could I do it with another loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of struggling with the syntax, just remove the variables from the loop declaration entirely and use a simple `While` loop.  For example:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = k
While i < j
    DoSomeStuff()
    i += 1
End While
```

Note that the contrived example you're presenting (used in this answer) appears to create an *infinite* loop.  But presumably you have other logic in mind for changing the values of these variables.  Overall the point here is to simply use a `While` loop and control the variables manually.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the provided example was good enough but it wasn't. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Nocxy: Ok, I've removed the same operation from the answer.  Though this now begs the question of why `j` is needed at all, since it isn't being modified and is just a copy of `k` which is equally available in this scope.  Either way, the main point of the answer remains.  If you want to track two different variables in a loop, the structure of a `For` loop is too limited.  It's designed to cover the vast majority of cases, but not rare edge cases.  For such edge cases, you can always use the simpler `While` loop structure and manage the variables manually.

Comment: In my case, ``k`` is a count of ``COM Object`` and every time I want to access the counter, it takes time. In an inner loop, I have to access values of these objects and I cached as much as possible to avoid wasting time. I think the final version will completely recreate the structure of this class with real objects. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Nocxy: In that case if even *reading* `k` is a resource-heavy process then, yes, reading it once and storing the resulting value in a variable makes sense.  If `k` itself presents as a variable, it may be worth wrapping its access in a method to make it obvious that it's a process and not just a value.  But in any event, the answer doesn't change.

Comment: If I had more time I'd rewrite the interface to the library but I'll end up recreate "real" objects anyway at the start of the program. By "the answer", I guess you mean your answer and yes, I think it's the best answer I could have gotten. Thank you